# Creating one window HelloWorld app with MainActivity.java file and Window.java file

Tags: android

I am interested in creating a simple HelloWorld application that has only one window. I would like to have it be it's own java source file named Screen.java. I want to call it from another java source file named MainActivity.java.

So far I have for MainActivity.java:

```
package com.microsoft.helloworld;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Screen Screen = new Screen();
   }
}
```

and for Screen.java I have:

```
package com.microsoft.helloworld;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

public class Screen extends Activity {

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
       FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
       fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
 return v;
}
}
```

I am specifically interested in how to create the window defined in Screen.java from MainActivity.java. What is missing here? What are my options?

Comment: What you are looking for is called Intent in Android. There is a good example in the official android docs. Have a look at: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to move the one activity to others. Add this code in `MainActivity` class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { //added March 3, 2019

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Screen.class);
     startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

You just mix up the Fragment code with Activity.

And the `Screen` Activity should look like this:

```
public class Screen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
       FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
       fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
   }
}
```

you have to add another layout for screen activity.

Comment: Have you added Screen class in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Hmmm, seems like I need to declare Screen.java in the manifest...I have not done that. That could be the problem!

Comment: Yes I will. Thank you for your patience.